# I need to understand the logic behind this cpp code

Tags: c++

```
int x = 25;
unsigned int g = x & 0x80000000;
```

how did this code read the most significant bit of in the address of x? does the reference to 0x80000000, or binary 1000 0000 0000 0000 accomplished that task, or was it something else?

Comment: Read about bitwise operations in C++

Comment: That binary equivalent needs a *lot* more zeroes, however, considering `char` is a signed 8-bit value that should always return 0. Do you mean versus the "address of `x`" as in `&x & ...`?

Comment: Nothing in the shown code involves the address of `x`. Without seeing more context and exactly what you observed, this can't really be answered.

Comment: 'How did this code read the most significant bit of in the address of `x`': it didn't. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: my mistake, this was supposed to be for an int

Answer (score -2):

For `char` the most significant bit is typically the sign bit as per [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so this should be:

```
 char x = 25;
 unsigned int msb = x & (1 << 6);
```

Where `(1 << 6)` means the 6 bit, counting from 0, or the 7th counting from 1st. It's the second-to-top bit and equivalent to `0x40`.

Since `25` is `0b00011001` you won't get a bit set. You'll need a value >= 64.

Comment: The *6th* bit? Surely *7th*!

Comment: @KenY-N Starting at 0th.

Comment: Try again, please.

Comment: @KenY-N Using 0-based indexing it's the 6th. Using 1-based it's the 7th. In many cases the bits are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. up to 7 in a byte. Hence "6th".

Comment: ...and the sign bit is? And let's not forget that a plain `char` may be unsigned.

Comment: @KenY-N Instead of getting pedantic here, can you please add your own answer?